MacOS applications terminal command empty apart from "join.app"
I'm helping someone out with their Mac computer, Macbook and files. Its overall, a disorganised mess.
Something I'm baffled and suspicious about is that when I open the terminal and go "ls", it returns the expected info.
However when I then "cd" to "applications" and go "ls", it only lists "Join.app".
And within "join.app", there is nothing.
I know that someone previously has attempted to sync some files between her mac and her macbook - and they may have used the join (https://joaoapps.com/join) app.
Am I right to be suspicious of this?
The macbook lists everything as I'd expect (e.g things are in the applications folder) and I can't find anything about "join" on the macbook's file system.
Photo attached of the Mac terminal.
Thanks
I expected applications to be listed when I'm in applications and go "ls".
I expected some information/documentation on Join.app for MacOS - no avail.
I did some basic network commands and nothing stood out to me as overtly suspicious (there were some extra ports open that are apparently not meant to be open)
I've attempted commands for hiding and unhiding hidden files - nothing was hidden so nothing additional was shown.

Are you refering to ~/Applications or /Applications?
